# Is it possible to make syslink's background transparent

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to make my controls transparent using `OnCtlColor` handler:

`Fragment.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "Fragment.h"
#include "resource.h"

class Fragment : public CDialog
{
public:
    Fragment(CWnd* pParent = nullptr) : CDialog(IDD_FRAGMENT1, pParent) {}

    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
    {
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(220, 120, 120));
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum
    {
        IDD = IDD_FRAGMENT1
    };
#endif

protected:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Fragment)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SYSLINK1, m_link);
    }

    CLinkCtrl m_link; // is syslink
};
```

`Fragment.cpp`

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Fragment.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(Fragment, CDialog)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Fragment, CDialog)
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

It works corectly for other controls, but doesn't work for `CLinkCtrl`.
However `CLinkCtrl` changes color when I switch it's `Use visual style` property in VS' resource editor (I think, it's changes color to system theme's one).

Update: I'm not sure why I have minused this question, but I tried to add more code.

Comment: what you want is a [mre], a small example that anyone with the correct tools can drop into those tools, compile, run, and see the same program behaviour (barring invocation of undefined behaviour, that is) without having to make any changes to the example. Sometimes, often with GUI code, the amount of boilerplate necessary to make the example reproducible makes the example quite large, but do what you can to eliminate visual elements you don't need to show to demonstrate the problem. Minimal just means, "I can't reproduce if I take out anything else."

Comment: Don't "try to add more code". Actually add more code. Where are the relevant parts of Fragment.cpp? Not my DV BTW.

Comment: I showed you full code for both header and implementation

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you don't need to define a new class or use `WM_CTLCOLOR`, as transparent background drawing seems to be supported natively. Check the [`LWS_TRANSPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/syslink-control-styles) style; if you can't set in the Properties Editor, you can edit the script or set it programmatically (in `OnInitDialog()`).

Comment: Recommendation: Careful with wishy-washy words like "maybe" in an answer. If you don't know if you have the answer, run some tests and prove it (and if the question does not make that possible, consider a comment rather than an answer). If you know the answer, don't hedge your bets.